# Update 1.6.9 to 2.5.2 Truncated content after commas/apostrophe

Tags: update

I'm in the middle of updating an EE 1.6.9 site to 2.5.2. Everything went smoothly up until I verified the content. For some reason any time there's a comma and/or an apostrophe the channel data and categories are all truncated from that point.

I've tried to research this as best I could but it's been tough to figure out. Has anyone else ran into this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to consider updating to the latest 1.x branch (1.7.3) before upgrading to 2.x. That's solved all issues for me in the past.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking it would be. Shame the docs make no mention of this though. Thanks Philip.

Comment: Yeah, I would actually expect the 2.x install to make all the appropriate 1.x upgrades... ah well :D

Comment: Where can I download version 1.7 from? I can't find it anywhere on the ee site.